# Teachers' Title

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm an English teacher in Iran. My students call me "Teacher..., ...", and I mind that. Is it usual in English speaking countries? I mean do the students in English speaking countries call their teacher "Teacher!"?

Comment: It varies. In the United States, it's common to call teachers _Mr._ or _Mrs._ or _Miss_ or _Ms._ -- at the teacher's choice -- _Ravand_ (or whatever their family name is). For specially learned teachers, _Professor_ or _Doctor Ravand_. The family name is required; _Mr, Mrs, Ms, Miss, Doctor, Professor_ by themselves are impolite -- only the respected title is a proper vocative.

Comment: What about it bothers you, and why? What might you prefer that they call you? Are they just translating a local custom into English? How old are these people?  It is not uncommon to hear **very** young children crying *Teacher! Billy just pinched me!* or some such thing.

Answer (score 1):

In SEA it is totally normal to be called *teacher* because they see it as being very polite to recognise your status/position. In Indonesia you normally get *Mister* which is a translation of their L1 *bapak*, and I believe it is the same in Malysia though I have no direct experience.

'Mr [family name]' is practically unheard around here, though sometimes you may get Mr[given name] from younger students.

If you are going to teach abroad, you have to accept that different countries have different ideas about polite terms of address and be happy with being called *teacher*.

Comment: What does 'SEA' mean?

Comment: @Mitch My guess is "Southeast Asia" due to the mention of Indonesia and Malaysia

Comment: I grew up in Malaysia. Whilst 'Teacher' might have been tolerated in young children, it is not the normal address term: we often called male teachers 'sir' (and in the UK female teachers are often called 'miss' regardless of marital status), but more generally title + surname (Mrs Ong, Mr Koh).

Comment: Yes... SEA is South East Asia, where I have lived and worked for a couple of decades. @Peter, I have worked in China, Vietnam, Singapore, and Indonesia, but never in Malaysia. being called *teacher* seems to be standard (except Indonesia where *mister* is common), and if I get a *Mr* it is followed by given name. Some things bear in mind though... I worked in IELTS or university language preparation courses rather than main stream, and as a British guy in a foreign land I may be treated differently - observers dilemma and all that.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, depending on the region it would either be

- ma'am or sir
- Mr, Mrs, Ms So&So
- usually a combination of both.

Among areas of high immigrant populations where their native homes might be accustomed to the case, they might address the teacher as "*teacher*", but they would soon learn the proper way.

Comment: Why do you see *teacher* as improper?

Answer (score 0):

Here in Ghana,  pupils or students don't call teachers by the title, "teacher"

It's either Sir or Madam. Or
Mr. Nyanor (surname) or Miss/Mrs. Nyanor.(maiden or husband's name)

Answer (score -3):

I think in America they do. Here in England it would be considered very rude.

Comment: In the US, it is ma'am/sir or Mr, Mrs, Ms So&So. In immigrant populations, they may address the teacher as "teacher", but they would soon learn the proper way.